# Data structure and file structure for storing append only messages?

Tags: algorithm, file, data-structures

A message is a bundle of data of variable size with a unique message ID(integer). I'd like to have a design/data structure/algorithm to:

1. be able to efficiently store the messages on the disk, the number of messages can be very big, length is variable. But there is no update or modification of stored ones.
2. be able to retrieve a message with a message ID, i.e. return the message stored.
3. recently stored messages are queried more often than old ones
4. each message has a TTL, need a way to truncate the file with old messages

What is the proper data structure and file structure for this need?

Comment: How many messages is "very big?" How often are new messages added? How many messages do you expect to be "live" at any time? What is the TTL for messages? Is it measured in days? Weeks? Are the message IDs sequential numbers? How often do you have to look up a message by ID? What do you consider acceptable response time for a lookup?

Comment: single message size range from 100 bytes to 2MB, TTL usually can be 3-5 days, message IDs are squential numbers. It's almost as often as to lookup a recently added message as store, response better less than 10ms, messages are added at a rate up to 5w messages per second.

Comment: Is that 5 messages per second? (I don't know if I should interpret the 'w' as a typo as an abbreviation that I'm not familiar with.)

Comment: it's 50,000 message per second, sorry.

Comment: Will more than one process access the file at the same time?

Comment: Apache Kafka is using an indexed segmented binary log file format with similar features. I don't know if it's original. You can get some inspiration from there

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking five messages per second, then you're talking on the order of a half million messages per day.

What I've done in the past is maintain multiple files. If the TTL for messages is measured in days, I have one messages file per day. The process that reads and stores messages creates a new file for the first message of a new day. This is trivial to implement by keeping track of the date and time the last message was received.

I also maintain a paired index file with each messages file. This, too, is a simple sequential file that contains message ID and position for each message. So to look up a message for a particular day, you load that day's file, do a binary search for the message ID, and then use the corresponding position to look up the message in the messages file. Lookup should be very fast within an index if the message IDs are sequential and no numbers are missing. If you can have missing numbers, then binary search works well. And with only 512K messages, binary search will be very fast.

To handle multiple days, you have the lookup program's startup sequence scan the directory for all daily message indexes and build a meta-index that contains the IDs for the first message in each day.

To delete old messages, you have the lookup program delete old files on startup, or have it do that at midnight every day. At that time it can also get the ID for the first message in the next day's file.

Or, the message gatherer can spawn a task to delete old files when it receives the first message for a new day. You can also make it notify the lookup program of the new day so that the lookup program can update its meta index.

With only 512K messages per day (5 per second is about a half million per day), you should be able to keep 10 day's worth of index entries in memory without trouble. Your index will contain a message ID and file offset, so figure 16 bytes per entry. Times 5 million for 10 days, that's like 80 megabytes: pocket change. To remove old entries (once per day), just delete that day's index from memory.

If messages have varying TTL, then you keep older messages around but keep track of their TTL. When somebody looks up an expired message, you'll have to do a secondary check on the expiration date before returning it. And of course you'll have to keep track of the longest TTL for each day so that you can delete the file when all of its messages have expired.

This is a pretty low-tech solution, but you can code it up in a day and it works and performs surprisingly well. I've used it in several projects, to great effect.